# Auto-format Driver's License using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an input box entering US Driver's License number. However, I want it to restrict to this format (A1234567) when typing.

I have searched for this but I can only find RegEx.

```
<input id="id">
<script>
</script>
```

Expected to have an auto formatted input box for Driver's License number.

(format: A1234567)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What you're looking for is "input masking", commonly used for phone numbers and dates. You can find some libraries on the internet, no need to re-invent this (unless you're willing to write the keystroke logic, the catching of arrows and backspace, keeping copy-paste working, accessibility, and all the other complexities of this thing).

Comment: Im looking for plain javascript solution. Is is possible?

Comment: *"but I can only find RegEx"* - Does that not solve your problem in some way, at least as a component of the overall solution?  *"Is it possible?"* - As mentioned in a previous comment, it sounds like what you're looking for is an "input mask".  A quick Google search for "javascript input mask" shows a variety of ready-made libraries and solutions.  Any of those would likely be a good place to start.

Comment: @Joseph No need to even use a library... it's built into the browser.

Comment: @Brad it is built into the browser for a javascript input mask for driver license in America?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, it's built in for whatever you want.  Hang out, writing an answer...

Comment: @Brad I will hangout for this... I hope this isn't an HTML5 form or isn't a javascript function that is built by you to do this... I'm waiting for a native function in Javascript that executes this with no library involvement. That is what a "built-into" the browser means to me.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers have form validation functionality built into them.  They can check a regex pattern for you.  Minimally, all you have to do is set the `pattern` attribute.

Let's first work out the expression you need.  I assume from your format:

- The first character is always a capital `A`.
- There will be 7 digits after that, `0` through `9`.

For that, we use the following regex:

```
A[0-9]{7}
```

Basically, this just requires a literal `A`, followed by `7` characters in the set `0-9`.

Now to use that in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="license" pattern="A[0-9]{7}">
```

The browser will show some generic error for input not matching.  We can do better than that though.  That's where the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) comes in.  First, wrap that input in a `<form>` element:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="license" pattern="A[0-9]{7}">
</form>
```

Now, let's add some JavaScript code check the validity every time there is `input` (effectively when a character is entered, or content is pasted):

```
const licenseEl = document.querySelector('input[name="license"]');

licenseEl.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  e.target.setCustomValidity(''); // Clear any previous failed invalid messages
  e.target.checkValidity();
});
```

Finally, add our custom message if the input is invalid:

```
licenseEl.addEventListener('invalid', (e) => {
  e.target.setCustomValidity('Enter a valid license number.');
});
```

You end up with something like this:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

As a bonus, you're automatically compatible with screen readers, alternative input devices, future interfaces, etc.

Here's a JSFiddle so you can play around with it yourself:  https://jsfiddle.net/k7g2bj9L/1/

For older browsers, you may want a polyfill.  And of course, always validate your input server-side.  The browser can be entirely bypassed.

Comment: what you just did IS NOT a built-in javascript way of input mask. You levied HTML5 pattern (Which is what I would do, not against it) in with a javascript event listener. It is the method I would recommend to do it, but you should have also asked if that was in the requirements of the scope. It was asked for a javascript, not an HTML5 with javascript.

Comment: Read the end of what I said in my comment again, but no this is not a built-in javascript method to do it.

Comment: @Matthew I read your comment, and don't get at all what you're on about.  The question refers to an HTML input, asks about JavaScript, and very clearly just needs a way to validate an input.  There's no need to ask if HTML is part of the question, because it obviously is.

Comment: Also, I would like to point out (Please correct me if I am wrong on this), that this has to be used within a form tag for the HTML5 Form Validator to work. This may not be used in a form tag and that is why it has to be in javascript.